# Bootstrap 4 mobile navbar

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a mobile navbar with bootstrap4.

When I try to scroll the navbar goes up without being fixed even with `fixed-top` in the class.

Sharing the code below

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top" >
        <!-- Navbar brand -->
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
          <img class="logo" src="images/logo.png" alt="logo" />
        </a>

        <!-- Collapse button -->
        <button
          class="navbar-toggler second-button"
          type="button"
          data-toggle="collapse"
          data-target="#navbarSupportedContent23"
          aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent23"
          aria-expanded="false"
          aria-label="Toggle navigation"
        >
          <div class="animated-icon2">
            <span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span>
          </div>
        </button>

        <!-- Collapsible content -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent23">
          <!-- Links -->
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="menuLink" style="text-align: right" href=""
                >WHO WE ARE
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="menuLink" style="text-align: right" href=""
                >WHAT WE DO</a
              >
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="menuLink" style="text-align: right" href=""
                >HOW WE GROW</a
              >
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="menuLink" style="text-align: right" href=""
                >LET’S CONNECT</a
              >
            </li>
          </ul>
          <!-- Links -->
        </div>
        <!-- Collapsible content -->
      </nav>
      <!--/.Navbar-->
```

The logo is 75px by 65px and it gets cropped a bit when I scroll a bit down in mobile view.
Sharing the screenshot below.
[image]

Comment: can you share your css classes `navbar`, `fxed-top` and `logo` please ?

Comment: its the default css that is present in bootstrap.css

Sharing it below

`.navbar {
  position: relative;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
}`

`.fixed-top {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1030;
}`

` .logo {
    width: 30%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }`

Comment: For the img try setting a height for .navbar

Comment: settinh height for .navbar will not let the menu item expand and collapse.

Comment: Yes. Sorry I misunderstood.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using **sticky-top** and also remember N**avbars require a wrapping** .navbar with .navbar-expand{-sm|-md|-lg|-xl} for responsive collapsing and color scheme classes.

```html
 
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg  sticky-top">
  <!-- Navbar brand -->
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
    <img class="logo" src="images/logo.png" alt="logo" />
  </a>

  <!-- Collapse button -->
  <button class="navbar-toggler second-button" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent23" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent23" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <div class="animated-icon2">
            <span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span>
          </div>
        </button>

  <!-- Collapsible content -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent23">
    <!-- Links -->
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="menuLink" style="text-align: right" href="">WHO WE ARE
              </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="menuLink" style="text-align: right" href="">WHAT WE DO</a
              >
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="menuLink" style="text-align: right" href=""
                >HOW WE GROW</a
              >
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="menuLink" style="text-align: right" href=""
                >LET’S CONNECT</a
              >
            </li>
          </ul>
          <!-- Links -->
        </div>
        <!-- Collapsible content -->
      </nav>
      <!--/.Navbar-->
```

Comment: I tried what you have suggested. It didn't work as well.

Comment: If you don't mind ,did you link the css and js files properly? I checked it in the code snippet by linking cdn (which I erased) and it worked perfectly.

Comment: once you add more content to it say another div after the navbar, the mobile navbar moves up while scrolling